# TYPO3 - "No pseudo-site found in root line of page [uid]" when create new sys_category

Tags: typo3

TYPO3 9.5.15

When I edit an existing category and than click the "+new" button inside the edit form, i will get the error:

```
#1534710048 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception\SiteNotFoundException
No pseudo-site found in root line of page 17
```

Page 17 in this case is absolute incorrect - this is the uid of the sys_category from which editing form I came from. the categories were saved on pid:6

I can do the same task from other category edit-forms, but not from all. I cannot figure out what is the difference of the categories where it doesnt work.

The basic site-configuration is configured and working, there is only one language, no workspaces.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Comment: Does your TYPO3 installation use the news extension? https://github.com/georgringer/news/issues/1335

Answer (score 1):

Side note: It still "works" for records which have the same uid as a pages record. It also "works" for L>0 records because they still fall back to 0.

However, this is not a core bug but a misuse of the internal DisplayCond by 3rd party extensions.

E.g. in the latest tt_address this is already fixed, see: https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/tt_address/commit/4501d1f30f3381a235e447567018e6d5646ec069

So changing the TCA DisplayCond of the sys_category slug in my own extension did the trick in my setting

'displayCond' => 'VERSION:IS:false',

Comment: I needed to update _tt_address_ and _news_ extensions